# Jquery mmenu sub panel with div instead of ul

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm using the excellent Jquery mmenu plugin to create sliding menus. I have a normal menu of ul with li tags and submenus with ul and li works fine, but I'd like to have a submenu that's more like a sub panel that has general content. I can't get it to slide in like a sub panel.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
<nav id="my-menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/about/">About with ul THIS WORKS FINE</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/history/">History</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/about/team/">The team</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/about/address/">Our address</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#div-slide">About with div HOW CAN I GET THIS TO SLIDE IN??</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="div-slide">
        <h1> About </h1>
        <a href="#"> close </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="header"> <a class="menu-icon" href="#my-menu"></a>

</div>
<div></div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4xQw6/1/

I found this solution, which worksgreat for opening a div panel. But, the href="#mm-m0-p0" which closes the div panel feels like an undocumented hack. There should be a better way.

```
<nav id="my-menu">
<ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
        <div class="Panel">                      
           <a class="close" href="#mm-m0-p0">X</a> 
           <h3>Login form...</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The id "mm-m0-p0" is added to the UL because the UL does not yet have an ID. If you give it an ID, you can link to that ID and it's no longer an "undocumented hack".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a div. You can simply style the `li` as desired. Add a css class to the `li`, and apply the desired format.

```
.liClass {
  display:block; // this will make the li behave like a div
  // add extra formatting here
}
```

I don't how you want the li to look exactly, but you can get it done with the appropriate CSS styles.

Comment: This sort of works, though I've found a better way using <div class="Panel">, instead of the <ul>. This allows a sub panel to slide in containing anything I want, though I haven't yet found a way to include the header that navigates back to the original menu.